# Binomial distribution - A statistical process control

Tags: probability

I have the following problem and I'm not sure what to make of part a).

[image]
For part a) I recognize that I need to find the probablility when $$ np > 3\sqrt{np(1-p)}$$

Solving for n I get: $$ n > \frac{9 \cdot 0.99}{0.01} > 891$$

So does that mean I need to solve $$P(X=891)$$ which does not make sense...

For b) I just solve $$P(X>1) = 1 - P(X\leq 0) =  1 - P(X=0) \\ = 1 - {20\choose0} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}\\ = 1 - (1)(0.04)^0(1-0.04)^{20} \\ = 0.558$$

Is that correct?

Thank you for your time.

---

For a) would this be correct?

$$ P( X > np + 3 \sqrt{np(1-p)} ) = P(X > (2)(0.01) + 3 \sqrt{(20)(0.01)(1-0.01)} )$$
                $$=P(X>1.53)$$
                $$=P(X>2) $$
                $$=1-P(X \leq 1)$$
                $$ =1- P(X=0) - P(X=1)$$ 
                $$= 1- {20 \choose 0}(0.01)^0(1-0.01)^{20} - {20 \choose 1}(0.01)^1(1-0.01)^{19}$$
            $$ = 0.0169$$

Comment: You have a problem all the way back in part A: what you wrote has no probability, it is either true or false. You want $P(|X-np| \geq 3 \sqrt{np(1-p)})=P(X \geq np+3\sqrt{np(1-p)} \text{ or } X \leq np-3\sqrt{np(1-p)})$.

Comment: Oh yes, but we still can't solve that unless we know what the value of n is. Don't you agree?

Comment: $n=20$ is given here. (Also, arguably the nonstrict inequalities should be strict; with a discrete variable it is possible that the numbers line up in such a way that this makes a difference.)

Comment: Yes it is!!!!!! Would the answer then be:

Comment: @Ian Good advice, but the problem says *exceeds* so I think they want $P(X\geq np+3\sqrt{np(1-p)})$ only. If the number of re-workings is too *low*, this is likely not considered a process problem.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland You're right, I didn't read the problem carefully enough.